# Parameterization Query using AddWithValue won't work

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am trying to learn the concepts of SQL injection and how to prevent them.  I understand that parameterization can help with this.  However, when applying it to my query it doesn't seem to work.  Here is my code:

```
string query = "Select * from Database where ClientName = @ClientName";

using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ClientName;
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(myReader);
                    }
                }
            }
```

My query works if I hard code the client name in or if I run the query in SQL obviously.  It just seems like it isn't accepting my parameter and that it is literally searching for "@ClientName"

Comment: what is the type of your `ClientName` column and `ClientName` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add the sqlDbType like you do here..

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ClientName;
```

this should work..

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientName", ClientName);
```

Even then, you want to AddWithValue instead of add.. so like this. The Add is the old way of doing this.. I have actually never used it in any of my courses.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientName", ClientName);
```

Comment: Yes, you want to use AddWithValue instead of just Add. Every time I've actually tried to use "Add" intellisense tells me that it's obsolete and that I should use AddWithValue instead.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is working correctly.  Also, I did not realize that this method would take care of apostrophe's for us as well.  Quite nice.